# UFuncType error appears when multiplying 2 different columns on Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to multiply 2 different colmuns something like below dataframe.

```
df4
| Column LIPQOH | Column Std_cost |
| --------      | --------         |
| int64         | int64           |
| int64         | int64            |
```

I have tried below code

```
df4['Value']=df4['LIPQOH']*['Std_cost']
```

### but unfunc error shows up like below

```
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-abf5bb958617> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df4['Value']=df4['LIPQOH']*['Std_cost']
      2 df4

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
     68     if _TEST_MODE:
     69         _store_test_result(False)
---> 70     return op(a, b)
     71 
     72 

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('int64'), dtype('<U8')) -> None
```

1)Removed NaN lines bu dropna
2)changed datatype from float 64 to Int

Assumption
this Dataflame contains over 4000 lines, few line may contain 'U8' datatype. but I don't know how to check U8 lines and how to fix.

Comment: Please try `df4['Value']=df4['LIPQOH']*df4['Std_cost']`

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Error has been resolved!!